# React Native , Flatlist diplay multiple things from the same element

Tags: react-native, display, react-native-flatlist

i'm a beginner in react native and in Stackoverflow. I got a data base which look like this :

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: "tomate",
    key: '1',
    title: 'La tomate',
    image1: require("./assets/tomate.png"),
    imageminiature: "./assets/tomate.png",
    link: "https://www.youtube.com,
  },
  {
    id: 'citrouille',
    key: '2',
    title: 'La citrouille',
    image1: require("./assets/citrouille.png"),
    imageminiature: "./assets/citrouille.png",
    link: "https://www.youtube.com,
  },
  {
    id: 'Poireau',
    key: '3',
    title: 'Le poireau',
    image1: require("./assets/poireau.png"),
    imageminiature: "./assets/poireau.png",
    link: "https://www.youtube.com",

  },
  {
    id: 'framboise',
    key: '4',
    title: 'la framboise',
    image1: require("./assets/framboise.png"),
    imageminiature: "./assets/framboise.png",
    link: "https://www.youtube.com",


  }
]
```

and I want to display to get something like that :[exemple of display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEDjz.png)
where you can see the title ,image , button with link. I already got element once per once but i want all displayed. I want to use Flatlist but if needed others things could be use. i'm not interested in the CSS code but more about an idea of displaying.

Thanks for your help
cordially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to render your data in list

1. Use Flatlist
2. Use map inside Scrollview.

**Example:**

```
import {View, Flatlist, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const  DATA  = [...Your data]

const Home = () => {
  const renderItem = () => {
    return <View>Your Component</View>;
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {/* option 1 to use Flatlist */}
      <Flatlist style={{flex: 1}} renderItem={renderItem} data={DATA} />
      {/* Opton 2 to map data insite Scrollview */}
      <ScrollView>{DATA.map(() => renderItem)}</ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: when you mean "your component" you mean an item or I need to create a component which got the view of all the atributs(I want to display) my items got. I tried FlatList before and i was able to display only one element of my item (like the title) and not all of them. thanks for your help

Comment: You need to create a component with all the elements.

Comment: Upvote if the answer helps you. thanks!